# how to rename key by using query in mongo Db

Tags: mongodb

I want to change the name of a key value in mongo Db

I tried to insert an object in mongo Db but a key of value was wrongly inserted

Answer (score 1):

For updating all objects in a collection
db.collectionName.updateMany( {}, { $rename: { "nmae": "name" } } )

For updating single object
db.collectionName.updateMany( { id: id }, { $rename: { "nmae": "name" } } )